# How to give navigation 100% width in pixels upon resize?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So basically, I am attempting to use jQuery to give my navigation bar (Bootstrap navbar) a 100% width, but in pixels.

Of course, this has to be determined every time the browser/window is resized.

I came up with this, although it is extremely buggy. It uses the starting width of 'nav' as 'navsize', and upon resize of the window, `navsize` still stays the same.

```
$(document).on('ready', function () {
    $(window).on('resize', function () {
        var navsize = $('nav').width();
        $('nav').css('width', navsize);
    }).trigger('resize');
});
```

I have also tried `var navsize = $('nav').innerWidth();` which was also no good.

The function is definitely being called upon resize since I have tested with `console.log()`

For all those who are wondering why I am doing this, I am using StickyJS to make my navigation scroll with the page. Although, since it is using `100%` width, upon scrolling it becomes much smaller since the `nav` leaves its container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
    $(document).on('ready', function () {
    $(window).on('resize', function () {
        $('nav').css('width', 'calc(100% + 1px  - 1px)' );
        console.log( $('nav').width() );

        ///  Use following ONLY if you specifically want to set the width in pixel
        $('nav').width($('nav').width());
    }).trigger('resize');
});
```

the `console.log` will have your width in pixel. Means whenever in future you will read the width , it will be in pixel.

`calc(100% + 1px  - 1px)` converts the width and sets in `px` units, which we can read later on.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that $('nav') exists?

I've done some testing using a basic bootstrap page and a slightly change of your code works.

Navigate to this page and open the console inspector.

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/starter-template/

paste the following code and you will see that the .navbar width will be logged on window resize.

```
$(window).on('resize', function () {
    var navsize = $('.navbar').width();
    console.log(navsize)
});
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

It'd be easier with the supporting HTML and CSS, but I will venture a guess based on the behavior alone.

**Best Guess**
It sounds like one of these options is likely.

1. you meant to use #nav, .nav, div.nav, etc and don't actually mean to select a "nav" element
2. your "nav" element is not display inline-block|block, which occurs in some browsers
3. you are using the "nav" tag in a browser that doesn't support it (IE 8)
4. your JS library doesn't support the "nav" tag

**Alternative**
Use JS to relocate your nav into the body (at the appropriate scroll depth) and give your html , body, and nav tags width 100%

Hope that helps.

Comment: I am definitely using a `nav` element, not a div or class. My `nav` element is definitely `display:block`. I am testing on the latest version of Chrome, and the same problem occurred on many other browsers. The jQuery library I am using is the latest stable release which does support HTML5 elements. I managed to get it working perfectly with @Nis code that he provided.

Comment: Would you mind sharing code samples before/after for my own and other curiosity/reference?